# A proposition on Poisson Structures .

Tags: lie-algebras, classical-mechanics, poisson-geometry

I was reading Poisson structure on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ , here is the

> Proposition - "Let {.,.} be a Poisson Structure on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ .then for any $f,g \in C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R})$" the following relation holds -
>   $\{f,g\} = \sum_{i,j = 1}^{n} \{x_{i},x_{j}\} \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_{i}}}\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x_{j}}}$ .

Actually after this i would construct a matrix with entries $\{x_{i},x_{j}\}$ i got that from the properties of Poisson bracket that the diagonal entries of this matrix will be $0$ and that it will be a skew symmetric matrix also for the remaining entries I would compute $\{x_{i},x_{j}\}$ , how  do i do  that, any approach?

I have read the properties of Poisson brackets like Skew symmetric , Jacobi identity , Leibniz rule.I think here $x_{i},x_{j}$ are generalized coordinates.

I am new to this and perhaps this can be a silly question but still i am unable to get a reference and even tried in chats too.

If anyone could cite a reference that would be extremely helpful! Thank you!

Comment: See the answers and links given in the comments [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/263881/a-proposition-on-poisson-structures).

Comment: I'm not sure this is relevant to the control tag, so I'm editing the post to remove it.